How to disable a user in Active Directory using Node.js
I'm working on a NestJS project that manages AD users, and I need to create a function to disable a user in AD. I'm using activedirectory and activedirectory2, but I couldn't find a function to deactivate the user. Does anyone know if there's a way to disable an Active Directory user using Node.js?
I tried using the activedirectory and activedirectory2 packages but without success, as apparently, there is no function to change the "userAccountControl" property to 0x0002 or 514, which means the user is disabled.
